# Unable to get internet connection in cloudera VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am unable to connect to internet from Cloudera VM. I have 2 network adapters under network settings in Oracle VM,NAT and Bridged

In both cable connection options are checked Please let me know the configuration changes I have to do

I am able to ping 8.8.8.8

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=9.48 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=9.68 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=8.28 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=8.88 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=8.41 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=8.35 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7440ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.282/10.216/14.378/2.416 ms
```

Routing table information

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: Let's start with posting your current configuration here.

Answer (score 1):

You can currently access the Internet through `eth0` since you can ping 8.8.8.8 from the VM. It seems that this could be a DNS issue. First, let's see if DNS is properly allowed outbound:

Run `nslookup` by itself and do the following:

> >server 8.8.8.8
>   Default server: 8.8.8.8
>   Address: 8.8.8.8#53
>   > www.google.com
>   Server:       8.8.8.8
>   Address:  8.8.8.8#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   Name: www.google.com
>   Address: 172.217.2.132

If you get a response from this (like shown in the example), then you need to modify `/etc/resolv.conf` to use a proper DNS server. Keep in mind that the Linux distribution may overwrite this file so check the documentation to make sure this is where you need to put it as there are different options for different distributions of Linux:

> /etc/resolv.conf
>   nameserver 8.8.8.8.

Once done, try to `ping www.google.com` and see if you get a response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.I have added the entries in /etc/resolv.conf file , Still I am not able to ping www.google.com.Current conf file entry - # Generated by NetworkManager
search cloudera
nameserver 8.8.8.8

Do I have restart anything ? Appreciate your help

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart anything. If you run `nslookup` by itself like I had mentioned above, does it work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working , I am pasting the nslookup commands -[cloudera@quickstart etc]$ nslookup
> ping www.google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
>

Comment: I believe you are running the commands wrong. Please run them in the following order: `nslookup` Then, at the ">" prompt, type `server 8.8.8.8`. At the next prompt, just type `www.google.com` and see if anything comes back. If nothing does, try `server 4.2.2.2` and see if that works. If not, it's possible DNS is being blocked by an upstream device like a firewall. Is your VM behind a firewall?

Comment: I have disable the firewall and tried re-running , still facing same issue.Please find the command logs below ---------------------------------------[cloudera@quickstart etc]$ sudo -su root
[root@quickstart etc]# iptables-save > /root/firewall.rules
[root@quickstart etc]# cat /root/firewall.rules
[root@quickstart etc]# chkconfig iptables off
[root@quickstart etc]# /etc/init.d/iptables stop
[root@quickstart etc]# nslookup
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
> www.google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
>

Comment: Thanks for the information. Try `server 4.2.2.2` and then `www.google.com` to see if that yields better results. If it still doesn't work, you need to speak with your VM hosting provider (Cloudera) to see why UDP/53 is being blocked upstream and/or if they provide their own DNS servers for people to use. If they do provide them, use those instead of 8.8.8.8 or 4.2.2.2 and let us know how it goes.